# http to https including www 301 redirect

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, https, 301-redirect, magento

I currently have our Magento website to redirect http to https. Basically the site should only be accessed through https including the www.

I think it is working however, it currently shows as a 302 redirect and I'd like to make this into a 301. Could someone let me know how to get this working? I've tried a few different things using the .htaccess but no luck. In fact when the 301 redirect is in the .htaccess file non of our existing redirect works and instead goes straight to the homepage this is the main problem I have.

```
# Redirect all "not correct" domain to www with https
# (is not important if comes with or without https):
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.gloveclub.co.uk$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.gloveclub.co.uk/$1 [L,R=301]

# Redirect all non-ssl to ssl.
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.gloveclub.co.uk/$1 [R,L]
```

My original .htaccess file contents are below;

```
############################################
## uncomment these lines for CGI mode
## make sure to specify the correct cgi php binary file name
## it might be /cgi-bin/php-cgi

#    Action php5-cgi /cgi-bin/php5-cgi
#    AddHandler php5-cgi .php

############################################
## GoDaddy specific options

#   Options -MultiViews

## you might also need to add this line to php.ini
##     cgi.fix_pathinfo = 1
## if it still doesn't work, rename php.ini to php5.ini

############################################
## this line is specific for 1and1 hosting

#AddType x-mapp-php5 .php
#AddHandler x-mapp-php5 .php

############################################
## default index file

DirectoryIndex index.php

<IfModule mod_php5.c>

############################################
## adjust memory limit

#php_value memory_limit 64M
php_value memory_limit 256M
php_value max_execution_time 18000

############################################
## disable magic quotes for php request vars

php_flag magic_quotes_gpc off

############################################
## disable automatic session start
## before autoload was initialized

php_flag session.auto_start off

############################################
## enable resulting html compression

php_flag zlib.output_compression on

###########################################
# disable user agent verification to not break multiple image upload

php_flag suhosin.session.cryptua off

###########################################
# turn off compatibility with PHP4 when dealing with objects

php_flag zend.ze1_compatibility_mode Off

</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_security.c>
###########################################
# disable POST processing to not break multiple image upload

SecFilterEngine Off
SecFilterScanPOST Off
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_deflate.c>

############################################
## enable apache served files compression
## http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#gzip

# Insert filter on all content
SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
# Insert filter on selected content types only
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml text/css text/javascript

# Netscape 4.x has some problems...
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html

# Netscape 4.06-4.08 have some more problems
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip

# MSIE masquerades as Netscape, but it is fine
BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html

# Don't compress images
SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \.(?:gif|jpe?g|png)$ no-gzip dont-vary

# Make sure proxies don't deliver the wrong content
Header append Vary User-Agent env=!dont-vary

</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>

############################################
## make HTTPS env vars available for CGI mode

SSLOptions StdEnvVars

</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

############################################
## enable rewrites

Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

############################################
## you can put here your magento root folder
## path relative to web root

#RewriteBase /magento/

############################################
## uncomment next line to enable light API calls processing

#    RewriteRule ^api/([a-z][0-9a-z_]+)/?$ api.php?type=$1 [QSA,L]

############################################
## rewrite API2 calls to api.php (by now it is REST only)

RewriteRule ^api/rest api.php?type=rest [QSA,L]

############################################
## workaround for HTTP authorization
## in CGI environment

RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

############################################
## TRACE and TRACK HTTP methods disabled to prevent XSS attacks

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^TRAC[EK]
RewriteRule .* - [L,R=405]

############################################
## redirect for mobile user agents

#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/mobiledirectoryhere/.*$
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android|blackberry|ipad|iphone|ipod|iemobile|opera mobile|palmos|webos|googlebot-mobile" [NC]
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /mobiledirectoryhere/ [L,R=302]

############################################
## always send 404 on missing files in these folders

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(media|skin|js)/

############################################
## never rewrite for existing files, directories and links

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

############################################
## rewrite everything else to index.php
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]

</IfModule>


############################################
## Prevent character encoding issues from server overrides
## If you still have problems, use the second line instead

AddDefaultCharset Off
#AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

<IfModule mod_expires.c>

############################################
## Add default Expires header
## http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#expires

ExpiresActive On
ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 year"

</IfModule>

############################################
## By default allow all access

Order allow,deny
Allow from all

###########################################
## Deny access to release notes to prevent disclosure of the installed Magento version

<Files RELEASE_NOTES.txt>
order allow,deny
        deny from all
    </Files>

############################################
## If running in cluster environment, uncomment this
## http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#etags

#FileETag none

<FilesMatch "\.(ico|pdf|flv|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js|css|swf)(\.gz)?$">
Header set Expires "Thu, 15 Apr 2012 20:00:00 GMT"
</FilesMatch>

<FilesMatch "\.(ico|pdf|flv|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js|css|swf)(\.gz)?$">
Header unset ETag
FileETag None
</FilesMatch>

<FilesMatch "\.(ico|pdf|flv|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js|css|swf)(\.gz)?$">
Header set Expires "Thu, 15 Apr 2012 20:00:00 GMT"
Header unset ETag
FileETag None
</FilesMatch>

############################################

## compress text, html, javascript, css, xml:

AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain

AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html

AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml

AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css

AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml

AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml

AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml

AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript

AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript

# Or, compress certain file types by extension:

<files *.html>

SetOutputFilter DEFLATE

</files>

###########################################

############################################

##

<IfModule mod_expires.c>

# Enable expirations

ExpiresActive On

# Default directive

ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 month"

# My favicon

ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 year?

# Images

ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 month"

ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 month"

ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 month"

ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 month"

# CSS

ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month?

# Javascript

ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 year"

</IfModule>

############################################
```

Thanks
p4rma

Comment: Can you post your existing redirect code?

Comment: # Redirect all "not correct" domain to www with https
# (is not important if comes with or without https):
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.gloveclub.co.uk/$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.gloveclub.co.uk//$1 [L,R=301]
# Redirect all non-ssl to ssl.
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.gloveclub.co.uk/$1 [R,L]

Comment: You'll need to add it to your question, with formatting.

Comment: Ok thanks, will work out how to format this properly and add to original question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you have two separate problems.

First is the HTTPS redirect - the snippet below will redirect all traffic from HTTP to HTTPS, regardless of its destination, with a HTTP 301 code:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

You then want to redirect non-www requests, again with a 301 response code:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^gloveclub.co.uk [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.gloveclub.co.uk/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Note that the ordering of these redirects is important - you want to catch the HTTP redirect before your non-www redirect, and your second rule will only apply to HTTPS requests.

Verification:

- http://www.gloveclub.co.uk/blog redirects to https://www.gloveclub.co.uk/blog/ (confirming the HTTPS redirect)
- https://gloveclub.co.uk/blog redirects to https://www.gloveclub.co.uk/blog (confirming the www redirect)
- http://gloveclub.co.uk/blog redirects to https://www.gloveclub.co.uk/blog (confirming both the HTTPS and www redirects)

Comment: So you're saying if I put it in the correct order I won't have the same issue? I tried the above in both orders however, the requested path redirects to the homepage.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't replicate your problem - for me, every request works as intended. Have you tried clearing your browser cache or using a different browser or computer?

Comment: Hi, I've removed the above code from the .htaccess file. However, I can try again now and clear cache and reindex.

Comment: I see however, that code still hasn't been added to the .htaccess file so currently these are all 302 redirects. When I do add the code it always redirects to the homepage.

Comment: Do you have any other rules in your .htaccess file other than the redirects? If yes, can you add the entire contents of the file to your question?

Comment: I've added the contents of the .htaccess file however, I've omitted any of the redirect commands.

Comment: Hi Craig, did you have a chance to look at the htaccess file above?